# Webdriver getText not returning any meaningful value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following html in a page

```
<div class="mst_updt" style=""> 27/06/2017 12:02:31 </div>
```

I am trying to extract the dynamic date value between the divs :

```
 WebElement webElement =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mst_updt"));

 String text = webElement.getText();
 System.out.println("i am text : " + text);

 System.out.println("Most read 1 : " +   webElement.getText());

 String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mst_updt")).getText();
 System.out.println("Most read 2 : " + a);
 System.out.println(webElement);

 Boolean isTheTextPresent =  driver.getPageSource().contains("mst_updt");
 System.out.println("And did we find the string ? : " + isTheTextPresent);
```

you will see i am trying various methods , here are the results i am getting, why cant i extract the date and time ??

i am text :

Most read 1 :

Most read 2 :

[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on ANY (e4a9c548-6146-4685-9944-6b5d51308bff)] -> css selector: .mst_updt]

And did we find the string ? : true

Full Code which should help..

```
<div class="content">
    <div role="main" class="content-inner content-full-width">
        <div class="main-content">
          <section class="component-list">
             <div class="section group">
                <div class="col-lrg span-lrg_1_of_3">
    <div class="component-weekly-wrap">
        <header class="header-weekly-wrap">
            <h4 itemprop="name">
                <a class="section-title-link" href="example.com/static/survey-panel">Computer Survey Panel</a>
            </h4>
        </header>
        <article>
            <a href="example.com/static/survey-panel"><img alt="" src="/w-images/fa8edbd1-2c78-4415-9abf-334f7087ff8b/2/CTGRS17OA344213-370x229.jpg" /></a>
            <div class="col-inner weekly-wrap-details">
                    <p><p>Join our <a href="example.com/static/survey-panel" target="_blank"><strong>Research Survey Panel</strong></a> and earn an Amazon voucher for each survey you complete!</p>
<p><strong><a href="example.com/static/survey-panel">Find out more</a></strong></p></p>
            <!--<a class="btn download" href="#">More information</a> -->

            </div>
            </article>
    </div>
</div>
                <!--most read homepage updated START-->
<div class= "mst_updt" style="display:none;">
28/06/2017 12:38:15
</div>
<!--most read homepage updated END-->
<div class="col-lrg component-list-most-read span-lrg_2_of_3">
    <div class="col-inner component-most-read">
        <header class="header-most-read">
            <h4 itemprop="name">Most read</h4>
        </header>
        <div class="ol">
            <ol>
                <li>

                </li>
                <li>

                </li>
                <li>

                </li>
                <li>

                </li>
                <li>


                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

             </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: findElement "Find the **first** WebElement using the given method." as the Documentation says. So: Any chance that there are multiple divs with that class and the first one is empty? You could test it by doing findElements (plural) and checking the size of the result you get.

Comment: What does it return if you use `element.getAttribute("innerHTML");`?

Comment: Thank you Rafal, that solved it. 

using both  by.css.selector and by.xpath

many thanks


      String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mst_updt")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
      String b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/section/div/div[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

      System.out.println("Most read 2 : " + a);
      System.out.println("Most read 3 : " + b);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was supplied by : **Rafał Laskowski**

i could get the value by xpath of cssSelector, it needed returning by using : `getAttribute‌​("innerHTML");`

```
s String a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mst_updt")).getAttribute‌​("innerHTML"); 

String b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[7‌​]/div/div/section/di‌​v/div[2]")).getAttri‌​bute("innerHTML"); 

System.out.println("Most read 2 : " + a); 
System.out.println("Most read 3 : " + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To locate a particular div to get text using `class` attribute must be avoided. `Class` attribute is applied to multiple div tags as required. You can consider using some other locator preferably an `xpath` or `css` to identify this unique div tag and use `getText()` method to retrieve the text.

Here in this case as you have copied the single div tag it would be tough to help you. But you can consider to construct an`xpath` to traverse the HTML DOM by binding to an `id` or `name` attribute at the parent level and then access the`class` property of this div.

Comment: have added more fuller code snippet.

have tried the xpath :

String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/section/div/div[2]")).getText();

but get the same result.

Comment: @MarkH Can you consider sharing the URL incase it is a public URL? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath, if that's working, it means the identifier you are using is giving you wrong element.

```
//*[contains(text(),'27/06/2017')]
```